# Passing string instead of object into KendoUI Upload data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, kendo-upload

In the Kendo UI Upload Widget, the `upload` function allows you to set the data object to be sent with the HTTP request.  If I don't want to send in an actual object, but rather, just a string, how would I go about doing so?

Here's what the data object expects:

```
$("#widgetId").kendoUpload({
  upload: (e) => {
    e.data = {};
  }
})
```

Here's what I want to send in:

```
$("#widgetId").kendoUpload({
  upload: (e) => {
    e.data = "";
  }
})
```

My reason for wanting to do this is that, the asnyc function is calling an Azure function and takes no parameters, instead it looks on the body of the HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you don't set the data object it will not send it at all.  In other words you probably don't need the upload event handler.